# Queries in RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

While using Spring Data Rest with latest version of Spring Boot, I have troubles extracting results of a query if the result is not identical to the entity. 
I reduced the class to the minimum, so here it is:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
   @Query("select u from User u left join Customer c on u.customer=c")
   Page<?> extractOnlyUsers(Pageable pageable);

   @Query("select u, c from User u left join Customer c on u.customer=c")
   Page<?> extractUsersAndCustomers(Pageable pageable);
}
```

First REST query (extractOnlyUsers) works correctly, while the 2nd query, extractUsersAndCustomers, produces this error:

> "Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [Ljava.lang.Object;!"

The error seems truncated, and it does not help if I set the log level to DEBUG.

I am pretty sure I have to provide some sort of converter, but I do not know how.
Here are my questions:

1. How should I instruct Spring to serialize the query results? Do I have to produce converters for all queries?
2. It looks to me the error is truncated, is there a way to see the full message?

I'm including the full error message:

```
2020-01-05 19:23:06.836 DEBUG 8378 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(user0_.id) as col_0_0_ from "user" user0_ left outer join "customer" customer1_ on (user0_."customer_id"=customer1_.id)
Hibernate: select count(user0_.id) as col_0_0_ from "user" user0_ left outer join "customer" customer1_ on (user0_."customer_id"=customer1_.id)
2020-01-05 19:23:06.839 DEBUG 8378 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2020-01-05 19:23:06.840 DEBUG 8378 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: 
2020-01-05 19:23:06.840 DEBUG 8378 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler#handleMiscFailures(Exception)
2020-01-05 19:23:06.840 ERROR 8378 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [Ljava.lang.Object;!

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [Ljava.lang.Object;!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:401) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:72) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toModel(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:55) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toModel(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:38) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.createModel(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:123) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.lambda$entitiesToResources$3(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:97) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:97) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toCollectionModel(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:80) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toModel$1(RepositorySearchController.java:206) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toModel(RepositorySearchController.java:203) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:187) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]

2020-01-05 19:23:06.841 DEBUG 8378 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
```

If it helps, my entities are:

```
@Entity 
@Getter 
@Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Table(name = "`customer`") 
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "customer_generator")
    int id;

    String name;

    Boolean enabled; 
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "user_generator")
    int id;

    String userName;

    @JsonIgnore
    String hashedPassword;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Customer customer;

    Boolean enabled = true;
}
```

I also tried this:

```
@Query("select new dto.UserDetails(u, c) from User u left join Customer c on u.customer=c")
List<dto.UserDetails> extractUsersAndCustomers(Pageable pageable);
```

With this entity:

```
@Getter
public class UserDetails {

    private final int id;
    private final Boolean enabled;
    private final String userName;
    private final Integer customerId;
    private final String customerName;

    public UserDetails(User user, Customer customer) {
        this.id= user.getId();
        this.enabled = user.getEnabled();
        this.userName = user.getUserName();
        if (customer != null) {
            this.customerId = customer.getId();
            this.customerName = customer.getName();
        } else {
            this.customerId = null;
            this.customerName = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class dto.UserDetails

Comment: None of the queries are valid, and the return type of the method doesn't make much sense either. What would you like these two methods to query and return? What is the code of the two involved entities?

Comment: Indeed, the queries are not useful, I used them as a handy example. The real queries are considerably larger and posting them here would make the question harder to read.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions though. What are you trying to achieve? What is the code of the two involved entities?

Comment: I have included the entities in the question's text. What I try to do is to run a non-trivial query and present the result. I devised a simple situation, where I want to present the results of a left-join query.

Comment: But this query being invalid, it doesn't make much sense. The return value should be Page<User>, not Page<?>, and selecting the customer in addition to the user is completely useless: a User **has a** customer. So just select the user, and let the caller do `user.getCustomer()` to get the associated customer.

Comment: Indeed, working with hibernate entities might work, but it's highly inefficient. Here is an example where HQL is considerably faster: "select u.id, count(c) from User u left join Customer c on u.customer=c group by u.id" . This example produce a similar error as described in the question.

Comment: Well, all the queries you've shown until now already worked with entities and returned entities. And this new query is also an invalid query. If it was valid, it would return a `List<Object[]>` or `Page<Object[]>`, so that's what the return type of the method should be. Here's the syntax for joins in JPQL: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join.

Comment: A more usable return type could be used if you used `select new MyDTO(u.id, count(c)) ...`. It would then return a List<MyDTO> or Page<MyDTO>.

Comment: The "MyDTO" solution looks good, but I still get this error: "Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class dto.UserDetails!". Query is: "select new dto.UserDetails(u, c) from User u left join Customer c on u.customer=c".

Comment: I'm not sure what causes this exception (it might be related to RepositoryRestResource: I never use spring-data-rest, and don't know how it works). But once again, your query is invalid. And since you're requesting User entities anyway, I don't see the point of returning a DTO, and even less of selecting both user and customer since, once again, a user *has* a customer. And the left join doesn't serve any purpose (in addition to being invalid).